# CLLocationCoordinate2D without knowing how many will be in the array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocation

I need to build an array using something like the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];


    points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116);

    points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066);

    points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981);

    points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267);
```

Problem is, I will never know how many items are going to be in the array, so I can specify the count.  Is there a way to create a CLLocationCoordinate2D array, and just insert new coordinates without knowing what the final total will be?

EDIT: My final goal is to use the coordinates to make an MKPolyline, using the polylineWithCoordinates method which needs a CLLocationCoordinate2D array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
// unpacking an array of NSValues into memory
CLLocationCoordinate2D *points = malloc([mutablePoints count] * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
for(int i = 0; i < [mutablePoints count]; i++) {
    [[mutablePoints objectAtIndex:i] getValue:(points + i)];
}

MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:points count:[mutablePoints count]];
free(points);
```

Comment: don't forget to add #include <stdlib.h> in that .m file AND, the function is sizeof(...) not size_of(...)

...just saved you 15 minutes.  :D  Otherwise worked great!

Comment: What actually happens here: 

CLLocationCoordinate2D *points = malloc([mutablePoints count] * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

Would be great if someone could point this out. We aren't creating a C array aren't we?

Comment: We are indeed creating a C array. See the documentation for polylineWithCoordinates:count:.

Comment: what is mutablePoints?

Comment: @igrrik it's just an NSArray.  I was following up on Dave DeLong's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Box them up in an `NSValue` object and throw them in an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: But I am trying to create an MKPolyline from this using the polylineWithCoordinates method.

Comment: You'll have to unpack them from your NSMutableArray then into memory with some pointer math.