# How to create a CLLocationCoordinate2d object

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I am trying to to call MKPolylines' `+ polylineWithCoordinates:count:` method.

How can I create a CLLocationCoordinate2D * object in this case. I have gone through this particular answer in  [CLLocationCoordinate2D without knowing how many will be in the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472057/cllocationcoordinate2d-without-knowing-how-many-will-be-in-the-array)

```
// unpacking an array of NSValues into memory
CLLocationCoordinate2D *points = malloc([mutablePoints count] * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
for(int i = 0; i < [mutablePoints count]; i++) {
[[mutablePoints objectAtIndex:i] getValue:(points + i)];
}

MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:points count:[mutablePoints count]];
free(points);
```

What kind of entries are in the array mutablePoints in the above case?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply what kind of entries are in the array, the answer is quite simple: `NSValue` entries. You can have a look at this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG) for more info on how to use `NSValues`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++)
    {
        float t1 = [[arr objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        float t2 = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        coordinate.latitude = t1;
        coordinate.longitude = t2;

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the OP's question!